# Accessing getHours() from moment js timezone object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to display the time on a webpage like "10:45" and have it keep accurate time/update automatically. If I want to do this in local timezone, I create a new Date() object and using getUTCHours() and getHours(), I am able to do this correctly.

However, if I want to do this for a particular timezone using moment js, I get "now_houston.getHours is not a function" from the code below:

```
function updateClock() {

var now_houston= moment.tz("America/Chicago");
var houston_time = now_houston.getHours() + ':' + 
now_houston.getMinutes();

document.getElementById('houston_time').innerHTML = now_houston;

setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
updateClock();
```

How can I use the moment.tz object to display time in this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must format it :

```
var houston_time = now_houston.format('HH:mm');
```

Comment: Or a one-liner `var now_houston = moment.tz('America/Chicago').format('HH:mm');`